# ¿Cómo vincular mi cuenta mi cuenta de Github con Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, git, github

Buen día comunidad de Stack Overflow, una pregunta ¿Alguien a vinculado su cuenta de Github con Android Studio (Artic Fox 2020.3.1)? Cuando quiero vincular mi cuenta me redirecciona a una pagina de JetBrains y me pide credenciales pero no conozco de que sitio son esas credenciales.
Lo intente con mis credenciales de Github y JetBrains y no tuve resultados. Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

[image: Ventana de GitHub para vincular una cuenta]
[image: Se abre el navegador y pide vincular mi cuenta de JetBrains]
[image: Me pide ingresar credenciales que no se cuales son]

Comment: No uso ese IDE (en general no uso IDEs para hacer control de versiones, nada como el CLI) pero _supongo_ que tiene cierta relevancia que github ya no acepta usuario/contraseña como método de autenticación. Tienes que usar tokens o cerfificados ssh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se supone que las credenciales para ingresar son los de tu cuenta de github.

https://github.com/usuario

Pero lo correcto para tener un mejor control de permisos y seguridad es usar un token que obtienes desde la pagina :

https://github.com/settings/tokens

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el token generado es el que usarias para autenticarte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma vinculas tu cuenta de GitHub con Android Studio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cree el token, pero aún no puedo ingresar

Comment: Añade los permisos que se muestran cuando creas el token!

Comment: Ya quedo resuelto muchas gracias Jorgesys.